# Functional Differential Eq. $ y''(x) - A y'(x) - B y(x) + \alpha B y(\alpha x)= 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

I would like to solve the functional differential equation
$$ y''(x) - A y'(x) - B y(x) + \alpha B y(\alpha x)= 0$$
for $-\infty < x < \infty$ and boundary conditions $y(x \rightarrow \pm \infty) = 0$. Here the parameter $\alpha > 1$. I am unfamiliar with standard approaches to such functional differential equations and guidance of any kind is most welcome!

**Progress:**
So far, I found the Dirichlet series solution (which is suggested by Laplace transforms)
$$y(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty C_k e^{-\alpha^k r x }$$
solves the equation but not the boundary conditions. Using this ansatz provides the recursion relation
$$ C_k(r^2\alpha^{2k} + A r \alpha^k - B) = -\alpha B C_{k-1}$$
for the coefficients in the series,
and taking $k=0$ gives a characteristic equation for $r$
$$ r_\pm = \frac{A}{2}\Big(-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4B} \Big).$$
Thus the general solution has the form
$$y(x) = K_+ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-\alpha B)^k e^{-\alpha^k r_+ x}}{\prod_{l=1}^k(r_+^2\alpha^{2l} + A r_+ \alpha^l - B)}
+ K_- \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-\alpha B)^k e^{-\alpha^k r_- x}}{\prod_{l=1}^k(r_-^2\alpha^{2l} + A r_- \alpha^l - B)}$$
which is a super interesting and nontrivial structure. The $K_\pm$ are constants to be set by the boundary conditions.

**Here's my confusion:** The series involving $r_+$ only converges when $x>0$, while the series involving $r_-$ only converges when $x<0$. How can I incorporate these facts into my solution? Can I drop the divergent solutions to get a two-sided solution

$$y(x) = K \theta(x) \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-\alpha B)^k e^{-\alpha^k r_+ x}}{\prod_{l=1}^k(r_+^2\alpha^{2l} + A r_+ \alpha^l - B)}
 + K\theta(-x) \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-\alpha B)^k e^{-\alpha^k r_- x}}{\prod_{l=1}^k(r_-^2\alpha^{2l} + A r_- \alpha^l - B)}?$$
The parameter $K$ can be set by a probabilistic normalization condition in context of my problem.

Is this application of boundary conditions valid? In a way it seems contrived since I'm allowing the $K_\pm$ constants to depend on $x$.

Comment: Why not to start changing variable $x=t\epsilon$ and rewrite the equation in terms of $y(t)$ ?

Comment: Does it help @ClaudeLeibovici? I derive (maybe some lost $\epsilon$ prefactors..) $ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} y(t \epsilon) - \epsilon A  \frac{\partial}{\partial t} y(t \epsilon) + \epsilon^2 B y(t ) = 0 $ which seems more of the same.

Comment: One interesting transformation I just found is $u = \log w $. I find (if I'm correct) a transformation into a delay differential equation for a new function $z(w) = y(x)$. The delay is $\log \epsilon$