# Fundamental confusion with two-sided boundary conditions in 2nd order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have a rather simplistic confusion with the application of two-sided boundary conditions in solving differential equations. As a toy example of my confusion, consider the differential equation
$$ y''(x) = k^2 y(x) $$ on the domain $-\infty < x < \infty$ where $k$ is a real positive parameter. The solution to this equation is trivially
$$ y(x) = C_1 e^{k x} + C_2 e^{-k x}. $$
Now I want to impose the condition that this function $y(x)$ is normalizable, which can be written
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm \infty} y(x) = 0. $$

Taking $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} y(x)$ I find $C_1 = 0$, and taking $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}$ I find $C_2 = 0$. Now I know the solution has to be $$y(x) = C_1\theta(-x)e^{\lambda x} + C_2 \theta(x) e^{-\lambda u} = C e^{-\lambda |x| }, $$
a two-sided exponential distribution. Here the second equality follows as the equation has to take the same value from either side of $x=0$.

I'm not confused by how to derive this solution, I'm just confused how it's valid to pick and choose where the $C$'s are zero and where they're not. The $C$'s were to be constant, but in writing the $C$'s with step functions of $x$, haven't I imposed $x$-dependence to them? Isn't this somehow contradictory?

Comment: $e^{-\lambda|x|}$ is not a solution of the ode in the classical sense. In fact there are no solutions with the given boundary conditions of 0 at $\pm\infty$. What is the context of this problem?

Comment: @Chrystomath basically I have various 2nd order differential equations which arise as Fokker-Planck equations for particles moving in certain random forces. The solutions $y(x)$ are to be probability distributions, meaning they should normalize at plus or minus infinity. May be a stretch.. but the above example could be the probability distribution of position defined across an infinite ensemble of particles diffusing around with probabilities $k^2$ to disappear at $x$

Comment: @Chrystomath please view the problem in full context here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3912115/functional-differential-eq-yx-a-yx-b-yx-alpha-b-y-alpha-x . You may be able to see what I'm going for with this toy problem. Would love if you have guidance.

Comment: I think what you're after is the Green's function for the problem: see [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_function#Example) on wikipedia.